# need to change this code to a do while code

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int number;
int min,max;
long sum =0;

cout << "Enter the minimum range: ";
cin >> min;

cout << "Enter the maximum range: ";
cin >> max;

for(number = min;number <= max; number++)
 if(number % 2 !=0)
   sum = sum + number;

cout << "Sum of odd numbers in given range is: " << sum;
```

This might be really basic for everybody but I am currently a freshman at college and has no background whatsoever in coding and I need to convert this code to a do while statement, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean the for loop that should be converted to a do-while? Otherwise there is nothing that could be "converted to a do while statement"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
number = min;
do 
    if (number % 2 != 0)
        sum += number;
while (++number <= max);
```